# Как разработать программу вычисления траектории свободного движения материальной точки, брошенной под углом к горизонту?

Tags: c++, математика, физика

Нужно реализовать выход координат (x,y), вводя время

Answer (score 4):

Издеваетесь, да? 7 класс, что ли...

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]